# Dice declaration error

Tags: java, class, enums, dice

```
Dice2 myDice2;
myDice2 = new Dice();
```

public class RecordDice {

```
public static void main  (String [] args) {
//Declaring the variables of sides and choice
int i;
int choice;
//Declaring the dice2 

Dice2 myDice2;
myDice2 = new Dice();   
//Asking the user for input
System.out.println("How many sides do you want your dice to have?");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
i = sc.nextInt();

if (i!= 4 )//||  6|| 8|| 12|| 20|| 100)
{
    System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number");
}
else 
{
    //myDice2= new Dice(i);
}

//Starting the do statement
    do {
    System.out.print("1- Reroll the dice");
    System.out.print("2- Get the value");
    System.out.print("4- Get the minimum");
    System.out.print("Please make a choice");


    //Gathering the choice for the switch statement
    Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
    choice = s.nextInt();

//Starting the switch statement with varying cases dependent on entry   
switch(choice){
    case '1':
        myDice2.reroll();
    System.out.print("1- Reroll the dice");
    System.out.print("2- Get the value");
    System.out.print("4- Get the minimum");
    System.out.print("Please make a choice");

    break;

    case '2':
        myDice2.getValue();
    System.out.print("1- Reroll the dice");
    System.out.print("2- Get the value");
    System.out.print("4- Get the minimum");
    System.out.print("Please make a choice");
    break;

    /*case '3':
        myDice.getMaxValue();
    System.out.print("1- Reroll the dice");
    System.out.print("2- Get the value");
    System.out.print("4- Get the minimum");
    System.out.print("Please make a choice");
    break;

    case '4':
        myDice.getMinValue();
    System.out.print("1- Reroll the dice");
    System.out.print("2- Get the value");
    System.out.print("4- Get the minimum");
    System.out.print("Please make a choice");
    */
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid choice entered");
}

//If the choice entered isn't the right value it exits the program
}while( choice < 0);

        System.exit(0);
}   }
```

RecordDice.java:9: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    Dice2 myDice2;
    ^
RecordDice.java:10: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    myDice2 = new Dice();
    ^
2 errors

> Exit code: 1

When I try to compile the program with the above two errors. Sorry for the long post and amateur code I am just a beginner at that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `myDice2 = new Dice();` Perhaps this should read `new Dice2()`

Answer (score 1):

in java, you have to declare fields **inside** a class, you can't delcare them outside

```
public class RecordDice {
    public Dice2 myDice2 = new Dice();
```

---

and it appears as though your inheritance is backwards.  Without actually seeing the class declarations for `Dice` and `Dice2` I can't be certain, but the naming convention suggests that `Dice2` inherits from `Dice`

```
public class RecordDice {
    public Dice myDice2 = new Dice2();
```

Answer (score 1):

change `Dice2` to `Dice`. I'm assuming you **do have** a `Dice` class somewhere and `Dice` **doesn't** `extends` `Dice2` class. Otherwise Please post the full code for `Dice` and `Dice2` class. What I'm saying is change

```
Dice2 myDice2;
myDice2 = new Dice();
```

to

```
Dice myDice2;
myDice2 = new Dice();
```

even better

```
Dice myDice2 = new Dice();
```

Comment: Can I paste bin you the code because I cannot work my way around posting the dice2 class code ? Sorry.

Comment: @bringmethejava If my answer really helps you to get the correct answer please accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If `Dice` does not `extends` `Dice2` than it will be compile time error.

```
 Dice2 myDice2 = new Dice2();// This is right.
 Dice2 myDice2 = new Dice();// This is wrong
```